# How can I use a script tag in handlebars? Everything I've tried isn't working

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm using Meteor with handlebars right now and I've tried breaking the script tags up with

```
<script> <{{!}}/script>.
```

There are no errors and when viewing my source, I see the script tags there but none of the scripts are actually working. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Possibly related/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: This answer is probably the explanation you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14002991/2068581, although this is probably a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14286986/2068581